# How to put scroll bar outside table in internet explorer CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I fixed the headers of my table using display: block in the CSS. I've also assigned fixed widths for the columns. I set a max height of 200px for the table which is why i need a scroll bar. In chrome it works great and the columns are all perfectly aligned. However in IE they are not aligned which is due to the scroll bar that is positioned inside the table for some reason. Why is it displayed differently and how can I fix this ?

I tried using bootstrap table which put the scroll bar outside of the table but the columns and the headers are still not aligned.

This is the table in IE
[image]

This is the table in Chrome
[image]

```
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1) { width: 72px !important }
th:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2) { width: 170px !important; }
th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) { width: 95px !important; }
th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4) { width: 65px !important;}
th:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(5) { width: 90px  !important; }
th:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(6) { width: 90px  !important;}
th:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(7) { width: 90px  !important;}
th:nth-child(8), td:nth-child(8) { width: 90px  !important; }
th:nth-child(9), td:nth-child(9) { width: 90px  !important; }
th:nth-child(10), td:nth-child(10) { width: 90px  !important;}
 </style>

<div id="page-content" style="">     
    <div >
        <div id="wrap"> 


            <div class="row marginBottom0px">
                <span id=""  class="1204 1 IHM textLightGrey textBold  " style="margin-left: 2%;"></span>
                <div class="textAlignRight"  > 
                    <a  id="export" class="col-xs-offset-1 cursorPointer telecharger vCenter btnLvl5 notUnderlined" href="<c:url value="download" />"><span class="1039 1 IHM size23px" ></span><img class="marginBtnLvl5" src="<c:url value='/resources/img/telecharger.png' />" />
                    </a>  
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class=" row marginTop0px" >
                <form:form  id="form" action="DetSup" modelAttribute="myForm" method="POST" class="col-xs-36">      
                        <div id="tableExport1" class=" marginBottom20px"  >
                            <table id="TableDo1" class=" tablesorter" >
                                <thead style="display: block;">
                                    <tr class="size13px">
                                         <th  class="1611 1 IHM odd textAlignCenter noBorderLeft" >
                                        </th>   

                                        <th  class="1024 1 IHM odd textAlignCenter header " >
                                        </th>   

                                        <th  class="1205 1 IHM odd textAlignCenter header ">
                                        </th>

                                        <th  class="1012 1 IHM odd textAlignCenter header ">
                                        </th>

                                        <th  class=" jJLib odd textAlignCenter header">                     
                                                ${myForm.today}
                                        </th>   

                                        <th  class=" jUnLib odd textAlignCenter header" >
                                                ${myForm.todayOne}                  
                                        </th>   

                                        <th  class="jDeuxLib odd textAlignCenter header"> 
                                                ${myForm.todayTwo}  
                                        </th>

                                        <th  class="jTroisLib odd textAlignCenter header" >  
                                                    ${myForm.todayThree}    
                                        </th>

                                        <th  class="jQuatreLib odd textAlignCenter header">  
                                                    ${myForm.todayFour} 
                                        </th>

                                        <th  class="jCinqLib odd textAlignCenter header"> 
                                                    ${myForm.todayFive}                                                     
                                        </th>                                                                                                                                                                               
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody style=" display: block; height: 120px !important; overflow: auto !important;">
                                     <c:if test="${empty myForm.myList}">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="8"><span class="1184 1 IHM"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:if> 
                                     <c:if test="${not empty myForm.myList}">
                                        <c:forEach items="${myForm.myList}" var="document"  varStatus="status" >
                                            <tr class="Do1 size12px">
                                                <td class="textAlignCenter">
                                                    <a class="tri" onclick="submitActionForm('myForm','myID','${document.myID}','doListeDetailFourn')">
                                                      <img src="<c:url value='/resources/img/picto_plus.png' />"  class="afficheCursor">
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>

                                                <td class=" textAlignLeft" >
                                                    ${document.myID} - ${document.myName}
                                                </td>
                                                <td class=" textAlignRight" >
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="monTotDo1 ${document.change}" value="${document.accountOri}"/>
                                                    ${document.account}
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="change1 textAlignCenter" >
                                                    ${document.change}
                                                </td>
                                                <td class=" textAlignRight" >
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="jJDoVal ${document.change}" value="${document.jJOri}"/>
                                                    ${document.jJ}
                                                </td>
                                                <td class=" textAlignRight" >
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="jJDoVal1 ${document.change}" value="${document.jUnOri}"/>
                                                    ${document.jUn}
                                                </td>
                                                <td class=" textAlignRight">
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="jJDoVal2 ${document.change}" value="${document.jDeuxOri}"/>
                                                    ${document.jDeux}
                                                </td>
                                                <td class=" textAlignRight">
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="jJDoVal3 ${document.change}" value="${document.jTroisOri}"/>
                                                    ${document.jTrois}
                                                </td>
                                                <td class=" textAlignRight" >
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="jJDoVal4 ${document.change}" value="${document.jQuatreOri}"/>
                                                    ${document.jQuatre}
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="textAlignRight" >
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="jJDo5 ${document.change}" value="${document.jCinqOri}"/>
                                                    ${document.jCinq}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                     </c:if> 
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <form:input type="hidden" id="myID" path="myIDSelectionne"/>    
                    </form:form>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the code that you have tried in fiddle or code pen.

Comment: Please share your code or demo.

Comment: @NimsPatel  I just added my code

Comment: okay i will check

Comment: have you use datatable js ? Please used boostrap table

Comment: @NimsPatel I tried it with bootstrap table as well, but it’s still unaligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Increased the tbody width from 100% to 102%.
Didn’t visibly change anything in chrome but it helped align the headers and the columns perfectly in IE.